# Unable to see Validation loss in Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow object detection api for last 1 year. As I am retraining my model again, I want to get a plot of validation loss. I don't see any validation loss plot in the tensorboard.

The training config looks like:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception Resnet v2, Atrous version;
# Configured for MSCOCO Dataset.
   train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "../data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "../data/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 1000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 100
  visualization_export_dir: "../annotated"
  num_visualizations: 5
  eval_interval_secs: 3 
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "../data/val.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "../data/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  num_epochs: 2
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the config file?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest OD API? The validation loss is plotted both under "Loss" and under "loss". On the first you can see the total loss and the split between localization, classification and regularization, while the latter only shows the total loss. Note that "loss_1" and "loss_2" are both the training loss, not sure why it's plotted twice, and there aren't split plots for loc, cls and reg.

Comment: yes, I am using the latest API. I found that only training using "train.py" does not run evaluation at all. I am only getting plots with name "Loss". I was able to get validation loss separately in separate directry when I run "eval.py" in parallel to "train.py". Am I doing something wrong? Or is there anyother way to do this?

Comment: Yes, train.py and eval.py are deprecated, you should use model_main.py instead. Interface-wise it's very similar, but it alternates between training and evaluation without any additional actions from the user (e.g. running another script).